# Wordpress: Condition Tags PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

This may be a simple one for you PHP experts out there. I need to give a certain `<h1>` to a post else show the page/post title.

I have this so far, it works if it is on a single post page, but when I am on a different page it just shows 'the_title' instead of the page title. I think its basically about calling a php function inside an already open php tag, if that makes sense. Here is the code:

```
<?php

if ( is_single() ) {
    echo 'News';

} else {
    echo the_title();
}

 ?>
```

The Wordpress tag for the page title is `<?php the_title ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing 'the_title' as a string, you need to actually execute the function like so:

```
if ( is_single() ) {
        echo '<h1>News</h1>';
} else {
        echo '<h1>' . the_title() . '</h1>';
}
```

Note the closing quote to halt the string, and the `.` to [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the WordPress function `the_title()`, and then another to join the ending `<h1>` tag.

Comment: Thanks. This has helped. I have changed the way I have wrapped the <h1>s see my post edit.

Comment: @Guy in that case just remove the '<h1>' portions of my code and the surrounding `.`

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way is to add the  tags inside the function itself, like this:

```
<?php the_title('<h1>', '</h1>'); ?>
```

No need for 'echo'.